# PHP Laravel Eloquent: has many-relation with child classes

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have the Relations...

```
abstract class Furniture extends Model{...]
class Chair extends Furniture{...}
class Table extends Furniture(...)
```

... also there is the room class...

```
class Room extends Model{...}
```

The following eloquent relations are given...

```
class Room extends Model{
    public function furnitures(){
        return $this->hasMany("App/Furniture");
    }
}

abstract class Furniture extends Model{
    public function room(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App/Room");
    }
}
```

Our goal is, that calling...

```
$room->furnitures;
```

... returns an array of different, inherited furniture objects. So if I do something like this:

```
foreach($this->furnitures as $fur){
    echo get_class($fur)." -> ".get_parent_class($fur)."\n";
}
```

Would result in something like:

```
Chair -> Furniture
Table -> Furniture
Table -> Furniture
Chair -> Furniture
Chair -> Furniture
```

Right now, that is not possible, because of the abstract class,  which is instantiated by default.

Is it possible to create such a relation in eloquent? If yes how to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use static reserved word. In Furniture make method like

```
public function getClassName(){
   return static::class;
}
```

And call it

```
foreach($this->furnitures as $fur){
     echo get_class($fur)." -> ".fur->getClassName."\n";
```

More info [late-static-bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)